# Seg Fault while trying to fill in a matrix contained in a struct

Tags: c, matrix, structure

I've got a structure for a matrix :

```
struct Matrice{

    int nblig;
    int nbcol;
    int **mat;

};
```

And my program's got a seg fault when i try to fill the matrix :

```
void initMat(Matrice *M)
{
    int j, i;
    srand(time(0));
    M->nbcol = (rand()%5)+1;
    M->nblig = (rand()%5)+1;
    for(i=0; i<M->nbcol;i++){
        for(j=0; j<M->nblig;j++){
           M->mat = rand()%101; //segfault here
        }
    }
}
```

It's been a while i've not practised C, anyone got a clue on why i've got this segfault?

Thanks.

Comment: You never allocate you matrix. (At least not in the code you show).

Answer (score 3):

I find it hard to believe that the program segfaults exactly at that line, but it's quite likely that it will segfault at some time if you assign a random value to a pointer.

You should allocate memory for the matrix using `malloc`; multiple times, in fact, if you use a double pointer structure. When handling matrices in C, I tend to use a different structure:

```
struct Matrix {
    size_t ncols, nrows;
    int *mat;
};
```

then initialize the `mat` member with `malloc(ncols * nrows)` and index with `mat[i * nrows + j]`. The indexing is a bit harder, but the memory management is a lot easier and some matrix operations likely become a lot faster because [everything is stored in one array](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `mat` member into a two-dimensional array of the appropriate number of rows and columns.

```
void initMat(Matrice *M)
{
    int j, i;
    srand(time(0));
    M->nbcol = (rand()%5)+1;
    M->nblig = (rand()%5)+1;

    M->mat = malloc(nbcol * sizeof(int));
    if (!M->mat)
    {
        /* memory allocation failed */
    }

    for(i=0; i<M->nbcol;i++){
        M->mat[i] = malloc(nblig * sizeof(int));
        if (!M->mat[i])
        {
            /* memory allocation failed */
        }

        for(j=0; j<M->nblig;j++){
           M->mat[i][j] = rand()%101;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to have (warning-free) access to the `malloc` function.

Comment: Ugh. Too much .NET lately. Fixed.

Comment: I thought I detected the C++ programmer's habit of confusing `<stdlib.h>` and `<cstdlib>` :)

Comment: Believe it or not, I do more C than C++. I really should have known better, but it's been so long since I have done either.

Comment: @Kustom666: I'm glad you fixed your problem. Please feel free to accept one of the answers to this question by clicking on the check mark under the votes for the answer you think helped you the most. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to assign a number to mat.  There are two things that look wrong with this:
- You need to allocate memory for mat.  Right now you have a pointer there, but by default it doesn't point to anything.
- You're assigning to mat directly, treating it like a single integer.  If it's supposed to be a matrix, you probably want to index based off of it (like M->mat[i][j]).  Allocate the memory first, though.